# Ensuring login is done once only in vertx

Tags: vert.x

Suppose I have 5 tasks to be processed. If no login is done, the first task is responsible to do the login. If login is already done, the later task should re-use the login.

I have 3 verticles:

- V1 is for performing the above logic.
- V2 is for checking with database if login is done yet
- V3 is responsible to do the login via web service

Since the 3 verticles are asynchronous, while T1 is being checked by V2, T2 gets processed by V1 (since V1 is now free). 
I end up getting both T1 and T2 making login to web service.

Is there anyway to ensure while T1 is being processed by V2 and V3, T2 waits?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need three verticles to do this. Perhaps sharing some code would help to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

We end up using Redis with transaction. When swarm of threads coming in concurrently, transaction ensures only one is allowed to do the update. The winner will be allowed to make web service call.